# Wrong Number of attributes while running Model.all Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a model to log all the activities from an API,the model looks like this

```
 class ApiLogInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :description, :parameters, :user_id                            
     validates :description,:presence => true                             

    def self.logger(description, parameters = nil, user_id = nil)
            api_log_info = ApiLogInfo.new
            api_log_info.description = description
            api_log_info.parameters = parameters.to_s
            api_log_info.user_id = user_id
            api_log_info.save!
    end
  end
```

When I run `ApiLogInfo.all` from the console it throws me an error like this
[image]

I cannot figure out what is wrong in there.It would be really helpful if someone can help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does api_log_info.save! able to save info into your database?

Comment: Before ApiLogInfo.all run reload! in your rails console. Hope it works now.

Comment: Does ApiLogInfo.first works?

Comment: Insertion into the table works but I cannot use any read queries, all,where,first,last,etc...all of them gives the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70904/discussion-between-sooraj-chandu-and-sansarp).

Comment: please add this on top of file and try once `attr_accessor :description, :parameters, :user_id `

Comment: That doesnt help @AmitSharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of `logger`.

There is a default `logger` method will be called for log SQL in `ActiveRecord`.

See this http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/logger/class